# How to change the font color and size in creating pdf file using php

Tags: php, pdf

I'm using this as reference: http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/

$db_data[] = array('first' => '', 'second' => 'hello');
I would want to make the text 'hello' color blue with font-size 12. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

### Please Read the [Manual](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/readme.pdf):

On page 20, following are defined:

```
 setColor(r,g,b,[force=0])
 setStrokeColor(r,g,b,[force=0])
```

And on Page 29:

```
 setFontFamily(family,options)
```

Comment: ok but how can I specify that I would only color 'hello' here:  
$db_data[] = array('first' => '', 'second' => 'hello');

Comment: How can I also use the tag <s></s> and display the effect in the pdf file?

Comment: @anonymous123, call `setColor` with desired color just before displaying hello and then again after displaying hello with original color.

Comment: inside the array()? HERE:

$db_data[] = array('first' => '', 'second' => 'hello'); ?